# Better way to create Events inside StateMachineBehaviour scripts (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state, behavior

I would like to use events on `StateMachineBehaviour` instead of using `bool` parameters. But I was having a problem using delegate events.

```
public class DeficateState : StateMachineBehaviour {
public delegate void DeficateEvent();
public static event DeficateEvent OnPoop;
public static event DeficateEvent OnPee;

override public void OnStateUpdate(Animator animator, AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex)
{
    if (!update) return;
    if (times > IdleTime)
    {
        update = false;
        times = 0;
        if(animator.GetInteger("IdleIndex") == 0){
            if (OnPoop != null)
                OnPoop();
        }else{
            if (OnPee != null)
                OnPee();
        }
    }
    times += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

I was able to unsubscribe manually. Carelessly when I missed some, errors like "m_Animator is destroyed but you are trying to access..." appears, making me spend more time to review my code.
Could there be more effective and better way of using events on `StateMachineBehaviour` without using delegate events?

Comment: What do you mean by _unity does not unsubscribe delegate events_? You need to do it manualy but you can unsubscribe.

Comment: are you simply asking "How do I do a UnityEvent"?

Comment: Yes I can unsubscribe manually but It gets more complicated when errors are rising up, and It takes me more time to review my code when I missed some event. I think UnityEvent would do.

Comment: What sort of errors you are getting? Regarding your current code, you should create two different delegates for two different events

Comment: errors from unsubscribed events ("m_animator is destroyed but you are trying to access..."). simply unsubscribing would do but. It's harder to unsubscribe when it gets more complex making it harder to trace the source of error.

Comment: I really still unable to understand your "unsubscribe" term and use. :( can you please explain it a bit more with extra code where you had implemented these events?

Comment: unsubscribing event is like this "DeficateState.OnPee -= <methodname>;"